# Does Xの時 need a に particle to indicate when something happened?

Tags: grammar, particle-に

I know that absolute time references such as 九時 have に after them to indicate when something happened, and relative time references and parts of the day do not.

But what about "time references" like 子供の時 (childhood) or 若い時 (lit: young time), do they have に after them to indicate when something happened?

Ex: 若い時に運動しました vs 若い時、運動しました (I exercised when I was young)